# How to open image in Instagram's sharing flow?

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, instagram, phasset

I'm trying to open an image in Instagram's sharing flow without having to download the image into the Photo Library. These two approaches work but they have downsides:

**First Approach:** This approach saves the image in a temporary location. It then uses `UIDocumentInteractionController` to open the image in Instagram's sharing flow. The problem here is that multiple apps are shown once the `UIDocumentInteractionController` is presented, I want to avoid this.

```
var documentController: UIDocumentInteractionController!
func shareToInstagram(image: UIImage) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://app")
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL!) {
                let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100)
                let writePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("instagram.igo")

                do {
                    try imageData?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: writePath), options: .atomic)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

                let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: writePath)
                documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: fileURL) 
                documentController.uti = "com.instagram.exlusivegram"
                documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.view.bounds, in: self.view, animated: true)

            } else {
                print(" Instagram is not installed ")
            }
        }
    }
```

**Second Approach:** This is a nice approach because it does not use `UIDocumentInteractionController`, instead it immediately opens the image inside the Instagram sharing flow. The problem with this approach is that you must first save the image into the Photo Library, something I want to avoid.

```
func shareImage() {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
        guard let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject else { return }
        let localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
        let u = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + localIdentifier
        let url = URL(string: u)!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to use the second approach without having to save the image into the Photo Library? The first approach seems to save it into a temporary directory first, would it be possible to do this in the second approach?

Thank you

Comment: Although Instagram's `LocalIdentifier` hook is fairly undocumented, it seems to rely on an identifier from a `PHAsset`, which can only be acquired if a photo is in the Photo Library. Therefore, I don't think you could use the second method by saving a photo to a temporary location, since then it wouldn't be in the Photo Library and thus would not be assigned a `PHAsset.localIdentifier`.

Comment: @aaplmath that makes a lot of sense, thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: Hey @Jay just wondering what you ended up going with here? I'm facing a similar issue and I'd like to avoid saving the image locally, especially since Apple's review team doesn't seem to like that.